# Cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl

Tags: java, xmlgregoriancalendar

My program needs to convert an xml file to another xml file compatible with sending invoices through our company program.

The compilation of the code happens without problems, while when I start the .bat file I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
class controller.ConversionWorker (in unnamed module @0x71c8becc) 
cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl (in module java.xml) 
because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype to unnamed module @0x71c8becc
```

This is the code where the exception is generated:

```
 private XMLGregorianCalendar stringToXMLGregorian(String data, String pattern) {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    try {
        date.setTime(format.parse(data));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.debug("ERRORE DI CONVERSIONE DATA: " + data);
    }

    XMLGregorianCalendar result = new XMLGregorianCalendarImpl();
    result.setYear(date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    result.setMonth(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    result.setDay(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    if (!pattern.equals(DATE_PATTERN)) {
        result.setHour(date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        result.setMinute(date.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }

    return result;

}
```

This code was written by a former colleague of mine and only he worked on it. Honestly I am not so much informed in java and how it is connected to gradle but unfortunately this code needs to be revised due to an error that occurs

In gradle-wrapper.properties i've add the:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip
```

I have installed the latest version of **Java**, **Gradle** and i build the code in **Intellij**

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 7):

You are not supposed to use class `XMLGregorianCalendarImpl` in your own code, it's an internal class in the JDK and therefore it cannot be used directly.

Create an instance of `XMLGregorianCalendar` using `DatatypeFactory` instead:

```
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;

// ...

XMLGregorianCalendar result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
```

See [`java.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html)